# JavaFX - Changing location of a Node after TranslateTransition

Tags: javafx, transition

So here is a problem. After each `TranslateTransition` (`tt`), I would like to change the location of the `Node` by `setX()` and `setY()`, then `PauseTransition` (`pt`) for a second, and reuse the `tt` from the new location. But before the `tt` runs in a new desired location, the button flashes briefly at a weird coordinate - more specifically, say a `Node` was initially placed at `(0, 0)` and `tt` moves the button down by 100 pixels. After each `tt` => `pt` sequence, the `Node`'s location updates by adding 100 to its previous x coordinate (`setX(getX() + 100)`) - the next location is hence `(100, 0)`. But before starting the `tt` at `(100, 0)`, it briefly flashes the button `(100, 100)` - after some effort to debug, I learned this happens because at the end of previous `tt.play()`, the coordinate "moved" from `(0, 0)` to `(0, 100)`, and hence when `setX(getX() + 100)` is used, it places the `Node` at `(100, 100)` and leaves it there until the next `tt.play()`, at which point the `Node` correctly relocates itself to `(100, 0)`.

Details:

I have a `Node`, more specifically `ImageView` onto which an `Image` is loaded that basically acts as a moving button on the screen. I used `TranslateTransition` to move around the button.

```
TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition();

tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(5), button);
tt.setFromX(0);
tt.setFromY(0);
tt.setByX(0);
tt.setByY(100);   // shifts the button down by 100 pixels
tt.setAutoReverse(true);
```

Here, the `button` refers to the `ImageView` object. After executing the `TranslateTransition`, I would like to empty the screen by setting `button.setVisible(false)` and keep an empty screen for 3 seconds. I would have the following:

```
PauseTransition pt = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(3));

tt.setOnFinished((ActionEvent event) -> {
    tt.stop();   // not really necessary though
    button.setVisible(false);
    pt.play();
});
```

Because I wanted the pattern of moving button => disappear and pause => moving button => disappear and pause to continue, I also let `tt` play when `pt` has finished. Also for updating the location of the `button` (new random location), I included `button.setX(rand.nextInt(500))` where `Random rand = new Random()`.

```
pt.setOnFinished((ActionEvent) -> {
    button.setX(rand.nextInt(500));
    button.setVisible(true);
    updateButtons();
    tt.play();
});
```

I have tried moving the updating line `setX()` both into the `setOnFinished` block of `tt` and `pt`, but it does not seem to take effect.

So my question is, after running a `TranslateTransition`, is there a way to undo its effect so it does not affect the `setX()` and `setY()` operations? For the purpose my application, setting the `cycle(2)` and setting the `Node` invisible after making half a cycle is not an option because I want to add other functionality that depends on timing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned that it is the best practice to explicitly `remove` and `add` the `Node` objects instead of changing their visibilities with `setVisible(boolean)`.

So when a `Node` object should disappear from the screen, it should be done through `root.getChildren().add(node);`. Likewise, when a `Node` objects comes back onto the screen, `root.getChildren().remove(node);` should be used instead. This approach fixes the addressed issue.